# Calculating correlation coefficient with ggplot2 in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, correlation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ggplot2: Adding Regression Line Equation and R2 on graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7549694/ggplot2-adding-regression-line-equation-and-r2-on-graph)

I used the following program to plot a scatterplot with regression line. But I would like to calculate the  correlation coefficient also. How can I get it with ggplot2?How can I add regression line equation and correlation coefficient (R)  on the scatterplot?

```
library(ggplot2)
d <- data.frame(x=c (1.0325477, 0.6746901, 1.0845737, 1.1123872, 1.1060822, 0.8595918, 0.8512941, 1.0148842, 1.0722369, 0.9019220 , 0.8809147, 1.0358256, 0.9903858, 1.0715174 , 1.1034405, 1.0143966,0.9802365, 0.7177169 , 0.9190783, 0.8408701 ) ,
    y= c (0.8550177, 0.8352162 ,1.0236998, 1.1071665, 0.6768144, 0.8449983 ,0.7616483, 0.8259199, 1.1539598, 1.4125006, 1.0511816, 0.9366184, 1.4101268, 1.2937913, 1.4147219 ,1.2943105 ,0.7859749, 0.6689330, 0.6940164, 0.8093392), names = c("A","C","E","D","G","F","I","H","K","M","L","N","Q","P","S","R","T","W","V","Y"))
ggplot(d, aes(x,y)) + geom_point(shape=1)+geom_smooth(method=lm, se=FALSE, fullrange=T)+geom_text(aes(label=names ,hjust=0))
```

Please help me.

Comment: The R function to calculate correlations is `cor()`.  And to find help  when you don't know the name of the function, there is always `library(sos); findFn("correlation")`

Answer (score 1):

The normal way of calculating the correlation coefficient and a linear regression is to that outside ggplot. Under the hood ggplot2 calls the `lm`, at least when `method = lm`. The solution to your problem is to use a mix of `lm`, `cor`, and `geom_text`. The post mentiond by @joran in the comments provides some good tips.